# Why are notifications not removed with removeDeliveredNotifications?

Tags: ios, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification, unnotificationserviceextension

Up until recently (I believe prior to iOS 12 release), removing remote push notifications from the Notification Center worked as expected using `removeDeliveredNotifications`.

Suddenly, without any code change in the Notification Service Extension, notifications are not removed anymore.

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    self.content = request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent

    guard let content = content else {
        contentHandler(request.content)
        return
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
        let matchingNotifications = notifications.filter({ $0.request.content.threadIdentifier == "myThread" && $0.request.content.categoryIdentifier == "myCategory" })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: matchingNotifications.map({ $0.request.identifier }))
        contentHandler(content)
    }
}
```

The function just completes without removing the notification. When debugging on a real device, it shows that `matchingNotifications` contains notifications and the notification IDs to remove are correctly provided.

For testing, calling `removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` works and removes all notifications.

The function above is called in `override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Hey @Manuel, did you find any solution to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Skaal No, it is still an issue. Please post here if you find a solution.

Comment: Can you post your complete `didReceive` implementation? I believe it's related to *when* you call the `contentHandler` completion.

Comment: @Kymer Completion handler is called after removing the notifications, see updated code. Again, it *always* worked fine for months until suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: From what I have read this behaviour indeed changed since iOS 12. The delete method returns immediately but executes asynchronously, calling the `contentHandler` unloads/destroys your extension (I assume) which may stop the asynchronous deletion. Can you try delay calling `contentHandler` for testing purposes? (delay for a couple of seconds for example)

Comment: @Kymer I will test this and post an update. Do you have a reference for this new behavior?

Comment: @Manuel It's not documented officially, just saw some people online experiencing the same behaviour since iOS 12. (a comment on [this blogpost](https://medium.com/the-guardian-mobile-innovation-lab/how-to-replace-the-content-of-an-ios-notification-2d8d93766446) by the Guardian for example)

Comment: @Kymer have anyone founded the solution? It's only iOS 12+ problem. I'll much appreciate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried the suggestion by [@Kymer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3947107/kymer) and verified that calling `contentHandler` after waiting some time (e.g. 3 seconds) resolved the issue for me, e.g.

```
// UNUserNotificationCenter *notificationCenter
// NSArray(NSString *) *matchingIdentifiers;
// UNNotificationContent *content;
if (matchingIdentifiers.count > 0) {
    NSLog(@"NotificationService: Matching notification identifiers to remove: %@.", matchingIdentifiers);               
    [notificationCenter removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:matchingIdentifiers];

    // Note: dispatch delay is in nanoseconds... :(
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3000000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Replacing content after 3 seconds.");
        self.contentHandler(content);
    });
}
```

So I think this means it's a timing issue, with iOS freezing the process aggressively after the `contentHandler` is invoked, and removing any pending removal requests in the `notificationCenter`

EDIT:
Although the question wasn't about how to deal with it, the comment section brought concerns about an arbitrary time delay. In my testing, posting the callback on another loop sufficed, e.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    contentHandler(content);
});
```

Comment: If an arbitrary delay is the only solution, then this must be a bug.

Comment: This workaround worked. I did not try to find the minimum required delay time, but empirically it is enough to use 500ms as delay. Side note: the delay may have a visible effect to the user in the notification center, because notifications are removed immediately when calling `removeDeliveredNotifications`, but whatever code comes next is executed after the delay.

Comment: BTW: you don't need to add an arbitrary dispatch delay. i verified it works by posting the callback to self.contentHandler(content) on another loop, e.g. the next poll on the main queue 

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    contentHandler(content);
});`

(sorry can't figure out code block in mini-Markdown)

Comment: @SimonBocanegraThiel that never worked for me, I used a 0.1 delay instead.